# Variable keeps showing undefined in the return statement

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am new to react and I am using the .map function to list categories and use the variable in the return statement. But everytime i add the variable in the return statement is keeps saying its undefined. I really don't know what I am doing wrong or how i can fix it. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
const NewModal = ({item}) => {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

    if(Array.isArray(item.modifiers)) {
        const cat_name =   item.modifiers.map(modifier =>
              <div> {modifier.cat_name} </div>
        );
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <a href="#" onClick={handleShow}>{item.item_name} </a>
        <Modal show={show}>
            <Modal.Header>Modal Header</Modal.Header>
           {/*Showing as unfefined*/} <Modal.Body>{cat_name}</Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer><Button onClick={handleClose}>Close Modal</Button></Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
    </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A short-circuit expression is commonly used in React to check a condition before doing something like an array map. This will save you the trouble of a poorly-scoped variable like you currently have with `cat_name`:

```
const NewModal = ({item}) => {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true);
    
    const cat_name = Array.isArray(item.modifiers) && item.modifiers.map(modifier =>
      <div> {modifier.cat_name} </div>
    );

    return (
      <div>
        <a href="#" onClick={handleShow}>{item.item_name} </a>
        <Modal show={show}>
            <Modal.Header>Modal Header</Modal.Header>
           {/*Showing as unfefined*/} <Modal.Body>{cat_name}</Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer><Button onClick={handleClose}>Close Modal</Button></Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
    </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: THanks for the response. That helped me out a lot.  Just out of curiosity what wouldn't it work inside the if statement. What if i initialized cat_name as an empty variable above the if statement.